# Random letter generator game

Tags: c++

Warning: I am brand new to programing! I am trying to create a random letter generator game for a class project. I feel like I have a decent start to it but I am having difficulty with a few points.

The program is supposed to ask the player how many games they would like to play(1-5). The maximum number of guesses they get per game is 5 and then it is supposed to print out what the correct answer was if it was not guessed. As it is, I have it so that it will run the correct number of guesses but not games and it dosent cout<< the correct answer when all guesses are done. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
#include<iostream>;
#include<cstdlib>;
#include<ctime>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char alphabet [27];
    int number_of_games;
    char guess;
    int x = 1;
    srand(time(0));
    int n = rand() % 26 + 1;  

        cout<<"Weclome to the Letter Guessing game!\n";
        cout<<"You have 5 chances to guess each letter.\n \n";
        cout<<"How many games do you want to play?\n";
        cin >> number_of_games; 

        cout<<"**************************************************\n\n";

    while (x <= number_of_games) //Need to get it for how many rounds, not how many guesses

    {   
        if (number_of_games < 1)
        {
            cout<< "Lets play game " << number_of_games << '\n';
        }
        //cout << (char)(n+97); //cheat to make sure working
        cout<<"Enter your guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        int guessValue = int(guess);

        if (guessValue > (n+97))
        {
            cout<<"The letter you are trying to guess is before " <<guess <<"\n"; 
        }
        else if (guessValue < (n+97))
        {
            cout<<"The letter you are trying to guess is after " <<guess << "\n";
        }
        else if(  (char)(n+97))
        {
            cout << "The answer you were looking for was " << (char)(n+97) << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Your guess is correct! \n";
            break;
        }
        //if answer is not right after x tries, cout the correct answer
        x++;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "nested loops" - an outer loop for games, and an inner loop for turns. I've used a `for` loop in my example.

Also, no need to convert everything to `int`. `char` is an integral type and can be used just like a number:

```
while (x <= number_of_games) //Need to get it for how many rounds, not how many guesses
{
    // Select a new char (a-z) for each game
    char n = 97 + rand() % 27;
    cout << "Lets play game " << x << '\n';
    // 5 guesses
    for (int number_of_guesses = 0; number_of_guesses < 5; number_of_guesses++) {
        cout << "Enter your guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        if (guess > n)
        {
            cout << "The letter you are trying to guess is before " << guess << "\n";
        }
        else if (guess < n)
        {
            cout << "The letter you are trying to guess is after " << guess << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Your guess is correct! \n";
            // Break out of the inner for loop, not the while
            break;
        }
    }
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your suggestion worked very well @JohnnyMopp